# Algorithm for spotting the "big" value changes in a list of measurements

Tags: algorithm, statistics

I have a sensor that measures the volume of a liquid.
This liquid will be consumed slowly and be refilled when is needed.
What I want to detect is the the times that this liquid is "stolen" or filled.
By stolen I mean sudden drop in the volume of the liquid. The opposite will be considered filling. Values taken from the sensor have smaller spikes that should be ignored given enough measurements that will help so.

Is there any statistics method (documentation) or programming algorithm (any language) or even better an sql function/query (any db) that does the above described scenario?

[image]

Comment: Are you looking for something like [Microsoft StreamInsight](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/ee476990.aspx)? Here's a nice [white paper](http://download.microsoft.com/download/F/D/5/FD5E855C-D895-45A8-9F3E-110AFADBE51A/Microsoft%20CEP%20Overview.docx) about it.

Comment: ... or a [link](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/14437.streaminsight-for-non-programmers.aspx) for non-programmers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are generally looking to spot [outliers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outlier).

1. Do you have a baseline value that you would like to keep or do you want to compare against your current running average?
2. What do you consider to be a sudden drop - is it an absolute term (like 5l) or a relative one (5% of the current volume).

Here is an approximate description if you are relying on the running averages.

```
on volumeChange do
    calculate new runningAverage
    if (runningAverage outside allowedRange(oldRunningAverage)) then raise warning
    oldRunningAverage := runningAverage
```

What you need to know is:

- how do the measurements come in (can you rely on them coming regularly)
- how is the `allowedRange` defined

Here's an illustration for a simple moving average (red) for 5 measurements (blue):

[image: SMA(5)]

Comment: what you describe is what I do now and its a logical and fast solution. It gives a lot of false positives though which I want to eliminate by using some "smarter" statistical method to detect and ignore volume changes that are not actual volume changes but just spikes in the values i received from the sensor. I do not seem to find anything on the web and its strange. Answers on your questions are 1(yes avg is what I use) 2(both are good. I use the absolute term)

Comment: @Judgemaik That's because you haven't defined your problem. No statistical method is good for everything. You have to decide what is important, and what would be a spike and then choose an appropriate statistical method. A spike is usually something that occurs once and returns to normal. A persistant change is something to watch out for. That's something I tried to do model with running averages. I'm adding an illustration to help you visualize how it works.

Comment: For me it is important to have spikes ignored and only get the differences on big changes that persist. I guess its not some common statistical problem with common solutions so I will probably improve the moving averages as I have already implemented to "calculate" the information I am seeking. Thank you for your hints!

Comment: @Judgemaik It is a common problem, but models depend on the expected data ranges. Common theme is trying to reduce "noise" (outliers) in the data. Moving averages do that for stocks (which have a lot of spikes). They are simple and most likely appropriate for your problem. FFT, Gaussian blur and many other options exist for different problems.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it would be worthy for you to take a look at [Microsoft StreamInsight](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/14437.streaminsight-for-non-programmers.aspx):

> Just as Microsoft SQL Server is designed to manage static data,
>   StreamInsight is designed to **analyze dynamic data**. To
>   StreamInsight, a stream is a sequence of data that has time associated
>   with it. Examples would be a stock ticker stream that provides the
>   prices of different stocks in an exchange as they change over time, or
>   a temperature sensor stream that provides temperature values reported
>   by the sensor over time.
>
> A **StreamInsight program passes the stream through a set of queries
>   that analyze the data, watching for interesting information. It then
>   outputs information derived from the queries, such as an alert that
>   was generated because a query identified an anomaly.**

Comment: I have checked this technology and it seems very helpfull in what I want to do. What I have not figured out in my fast checking the documentations, is what triggers the alerts? Do I have to write the logic? Do what I describe above exists as an alert logic of the StreamInsight streams? If I have to program the logic then its a very useful tool to be used for my case. I will look more into it when I have more time and maybe use it too regardless if it has the alert logic I want or not. Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome! I also believe that this technology will allow you to implement your functionality. Take your time wit some implementation examples and you will understand how to handle activity bursts / spikes.

Answer (score 0):

Computing the first derivative with respect to time should give you what you're looking for.  Using a time delta > 1 sample should help smooth out the small jumps.